# Best way to update DB table field based on Items curated (reordered) by user on front-end IN PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sorting

**Back-end:**
I have a table named item_curation having fields (id, item_id, rank) (MySQL)
It can have thousands of records of items.

**Front-end:**
We have a UI where all items are listed pagewise and user can either drag and drop to rearrange item's order OR user can manually enter a rank for any item.

```
e.g. A page has 60 items. User can rank item with rank 300 as rank 6.
```

After the user has rearranged OR entered ranks, this entry is made in item_curation table

```
id = auto-inc,
item_id = id of the item (from the main item table),
rank = rank assigned to that item
```

**I basically require a code which will rearrange ranks in order while removing duplicates not leaving gaps and retaining user entered ranks. Is there any predefined functionality in PHP? Or has anyone worked on anything similar?**

e.g. If user enters rank lower than its current rank, all the ranks from the given rank have to be incremented so that there are no duplicates.

```
[I1 = 1, I2 = 2, I3 = 3, I4 = 4, I5 = 5]  => [I1 = 1, I2 = 2, I3 = 3, I4 = 2(changed), I5 = 5]  => [I1 = 1, I4 = 2, I2 = 3, I3 = 4, I5 = 5]
```

Similarly If user enters rank higher than its current rank, all the ranks from the given rank have to be decremented so that there are no duplicates.

```
[I1 = 1, I2 = 2, I3 = 3, I4 = 4, I5 = 5]  => [I1 = 1, I2 = 2, I3 = 5(changed), I4 = 4, I5 = 5]  => [I1 = 1, I2 = 2, I4 = 3, I5 = 4, I3 = 5]
```

I have used array_splice for the implementation but it does not work when there is combination of both entering higher rank and entering lower rank.
In the foreach loop doing array_splice, the rank gets updated even though entered by user (has to be given priority)

```
User can not enter same rank for more than 1 item. However, user can enter a rank whose value is already assigned to another item.
```

Comment: What if user entered rank `5` for `2` items whose ranks were `4` and `3`? To be honest, I think you will need to add more examples.

Comment: @vivek_23 There is client-side error handling in which user can not enter the same new rank twice. However, user can enter a rank which exists for some other item already. So the only thing I require is a code which will rearrange ranks in order while removing duplicates and retaining user entered ranks.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thank you. I edited the post. I am using MySQL Database.

Comment: Honestly, this looks like a great way to implement a linked-list like system in your table. That way, inserting/deleting/updating would only require at most updating 3 records.